# 'When was the use of Þ diminished by the digraph 'th'?

Tags: alphabet, middle-english, digraphs

Wikipedia does not mention the exact date, nor do any other sites that I have visited.

While no Shakespearean book that I have read ( later 16th Century ) has the use of Þ in it, and the 15th Century *The Three Dead Kings* uses Þ instead of 'th', I have been unable to find any other sources to pinpoint more precisely the time period beyond the span of a century to determine when the usage was abolished.

Comment: Note that *th* is not a diphthong but a digraph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Etymonline the diagraph  ***[th](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=th)*** was used also in Old English though the use of the "***[thorn](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=thorn)***" ***Þ*** was prevalent. With the advent of printing  "th" definitely  replaced the letter "Þ".

> - In Germanic languages it represents PIE *-t- and was common at the start of words or after stressed vowels. ***To represent it, Old English and Old Norse used the characters ð "eth" (a modified form of -d-) and þ "thorn," which originally was a rune.*** Old English, unlike Old Norse, seems never to have standardized which of the two versions of the sound ("hard" and "soft") was represented by which of the two letters.
> - ***The digraph -th- sometimes appears in early Old English, on the Roman model, and it returned in Middle English with the French scribes,*** driving out eth by c. 1250, but thorn persisted, especially in demonstratives (þat, þe, þis, etc.), even as other words were being spelled with -th-. ***The advent of printing dealt its death-blow, however, as types were imported from continental founders, who had no thorn.***  For a time y was used in its place (especially in Scotland), because it had a similar shape, hence ye for the in historical tourist trap Ye Olde _______ Shoppe (it never was pronounced "***[ye](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ye&allowed_in_frame=0),***" only spelled that way).